# Linq query returning value from another class

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities

Just a quick question about LINQ, I want to use a value from the returned dataset to lookup a value and return this.  The line I am struggling with is .ViewingNotes = New Viewing(pt.ProspectId).GetViewings().Columns(7).ToString().  Is this possible?

```
    With BusinessLayerObjectManager.Context
        Return (From p As [Property] In .PropertySet
                Join pt As Prospect In .Prospects On pt.Property.propertyID Equals p.propertyID
                Where (p.Development.DevelopmentID = devId)
                Select New DevelopmentList With {
                    .Apartment = p.propertyApartment + " " + p.Development.Name,
                    .PropertyId = p.propertyID,
                    .Client = pt.Client.clientFirstname + " " + pt.Client.clientLastname,
                    .ClientId = pt.Client.ClientID,
                    .ProspectiveDate = pt.prospectiveDate,
                    .ProspectiveStatus = pt.prospectiveStatus,
                    .Agent = pt.Client.userID,
                    .ViewingNotes = New Viewing(pt.ProspectId).GetViewings().Columns(7).ToString(),
                    .PropertyStatus = ""
                }).ToList()
    End With
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an error? what is the `Viewing` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect not, when the compiler tries to convert the 'Viewing(pt.ProspectId).GetViewings().Columns(7).ToString()' bit to SQL it will get very confused. You would need to do it in 2 stages.

Do the first Linq-to-entity select first returning just `pt.ProspectId`, with the `.ToList()` intact. Then use the results to do some more linq, linq-to-linq if you like, where you can do the lookup using a lambda.

Comment: Ah, as I thought! Thought I'd ask anyway!

Comment: If there is another way I'd love to know, thats how I get this kind of thing to work.